# Then minimum value of $\frac{\sec^4 \alpha}{\tan^2 \beta}+\frac{\sec^4 \beta}{\tan^2 \alpha}$

Tags: inequality

> If $\displaystyle \alpha, \beta \in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right),$ Then minimum value of $$\frac{\sec^4 \alpha}{\tan^2 \beta}+\frac{\sec^4 \beta}{\tan^2 \alpha}$$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ I have tried it using Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality

$$K=\frac{\sec^4 \alpha}{\tan^2 \beta}+\frac{\sec^4 \beta}{\tan^2 \alpha}\geq \frac{(\sec^2 \alpha+\sec^2 \beta)^2}{\tan^2 \alpha+\tan^2 \beta} = \frac{(2+\tan^2 \alpha+\tan^2 \beta)^2}{\tan^2 \alpha+\tan^2 \beta}$$

So $$K\geq \frac{4+(\tan^2 \alpha+\tan^2 \beta)^2+4\cdot (\tan^2 \alpha+\tan^2 \beta)}{\tan^2 \alpha+\tan^2 \beta} $$

$$K\geq  4+(\tan^2 \alpha+\tan^2 \beta)+\frac{4}{\tan^2 \alpha+\tan^2 \beta}\geq 4+4 = 8$$

My question is can we solve it some simple way, If yes Then plz explain me, Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $a = \frac{\sec^2\alpha}{\tan \beta}$ and $b = \frac{\sec^2\beta}{\tan\alpha}$. Then we have:
$$a^2 + b^2\geq 2ab = \frac{2\sec^2\alpha\sec^2\beta}{\tan \beta\tan\alpha} = \frac{2}{\sin\alpha\cos\alpha\sin\beta\cos\beta} = \frac{8}{\sin(2\alpha)\sin(2\beta)}\geq 8.$$

Both equality happens when $\alpha = \beta = \pi/4.$