# Find minimum value of $\frac{\sec^4 \alpha}{\tan^2 \beta}+\frac{\sec^4 \beta}{\tan^2 \alpha}$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find minimum value of $\frac{\sec^4 \alpha}{\tan^2 \beta}+\frac{\sec^4 \beta}{\tan^2 \alpha}$

I know this question has already answered here [Then minimum value of $\frac{\sec^4 \alpha}{\tan^2 \beta}+\frac{\sec^4 \beta}{\tan^2 \alpha}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1966853/then-minimum-value-of-frac-sec4-alpha-tan2-beta-frac-sec4-beta-t) but my answer is coming different.

i applied AM-GM directly to two fractions and by changing terms of sec and tan into sin and cos and simplifying a little we get that
$$\frac{\sec^4 \alpha}{\tan^2 \beta}+\frac{\sec^4 \beta}{\tan^2 \alpha} \geq\frac2{\cos\alpha \cos\beta \sin\alpha \sin\beta}\geq2$$

**but minimum value is coming 8 ???**

Comment: Your bound $2/(\cos\alpha\sin\alpha\cos\beta\sin\beta)\geq 2$ is too weak.  You can tighten that to $\geq 8$ by using double angle formula for sine.

Comment: Right, so the expression is always $\ge2$. But $2$ isn't the minimum value, since there are no $\alpha$ and $\beta$ making the expression $2$ (since actually it's always $\ge8$).

Comment: @AnginaSeng but how we know that there are no $α$ and $β$ making the expression $2$ , and how we get to know that 8 is correct minimum in the same sense ?

Comment: @Ishan see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1966853/then-minimum-value-of-frac-sec4-alpha-tan2-beta-frac-sec4-beta-t

Comment: @AnginaSeng thanks,but i have already seen it and also i have mention same link in my question,but i am asking how we know that 2 is not minimum ?

Comment: @Ishan **Read** https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1966853/then-minimum-value-of-frac-sec4-alpha-tan2-beta-frac-sec4-beta-t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{2}{\cos\alpha\cos\beta\sin\alpha\sin\beta} = \frac{8}{\sin2\alpha\sin2\beta} \geq 8$$

Now why did the previous inequality only give 2 whereas when we use this we get 8? Basically, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are independent of each other, hence we can minimise the second expression by putting $\alpha = \beta = \frac{\pi}{4}$

On the other hand, in the expression you reduced to, both $\sin\alpha$ and $\cos\alpha$ cannot simultaneously be $1$, hence the product will actually have a different maximum value (which is $\frac{1}{2}$)

Comment: sorry,but still did  not get it , first of all if i have came to minimum 2 why i think to come on 8 ? and also i did not use fact that both sin and cos are simultaneously 1 ,i just use that they are always <1 whatever a and b is.

Comment: @Ishan You cannot maximize the expression $\cos x \cos y \sin x \sin y$ by simply saying that the maximum value of $\sin$ is always $1$ and the maximum value of $\cos$ is also always $1$ so the maximum value of their product will be $=1$. This is wrong because while you're figuring out the angle to maximize $\sin$, the cosine part of your expression is simultaneously getting minimized. If you want to think about the maximum of $\sin \alpha \cos \beta \sin \gamma \cos \delta$, it would definitely be $=1$ as the variables are independent, but in your case you have some common variables.

Comment: @Nikunj got it, thankyou very much

Comment: @Nikunj i was doing another problem and its solution here https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h212557p1172899 is contradicting what you are saying!!! i request you to please see the first solution in the link

Comment: @Nikunj in the end he says that $ \sum {\cos (x - y)} > 3$ which is false and reason provided there is same that i am mentioning above but there also we have some common variables inside cos ?? i am confused ..

Comment: @Ishan the maximum value that the $\cos$ function can take, regardless of its argument, is $1$. Hence $\sum \cos(x-y)$ will always be $\leq 3$.

Comment: @Nikunj so why it does not work same for $\cos x \cos y \sin x \sin y$ ???

Comment: @Ishan because the range of the $\cos$ function is $[-1, 1]$ the maximum value that any individual $\cos$ term can take is $1$.  $\cos(x-y) + \cos(y-z) + \cos(z-x)$ attains the value $3$ whenever $x=y=z$. If you look at $\cos x\cos y \sin x\sin y$, You cannot find any real $x,y$ so that this term $=1$

Comment: @Nikunj ok, but I was looking for a rigorous proof of this fact but anyway thanks ...

Comment: @Ishan Instead of rigorous proofs, you should focus on building up your basics first. How trigonometric functions behave, what happens when you vary the parameters in multivariable functions etc.

Comment: @Nikunj can you pls share a link or a pdf from where i can clear my basics ?